# Springboot JPA what happens automatically and what I have to code myself?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to setup basic persistance layer using springboot and h2 database. Since I never used non-query based database before I find it quite confusing. I created 2 Entities in ManyToOne relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "object_data")
public class ObjectData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "object")
    private List<UnitData> units;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long mId) {
        id = mId;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String mPath) {
        path = mPath;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String mName){
        name = mName;
    }

    public List<UnitData> getUnits(){
        return units;
    }

    public void setUnits(List<UnitData> mUnits){
        units=mUnits;
    }
}
```

Sub-Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "units_data")
public class UnitData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "objectdata_id")
    private ObjectData object;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long mId) {
        id = mId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String mName) {
        name = mName;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String mPath) {
        path = mPath;
    }

    public ObjectData getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setObject(ObjectData mObject) {
        object = mObject;
    }
}
```

Simple DAO:

```
@Repository
public class ObjectDAOH2 implements ObjectDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void create(ObjectData object) {
        entityManager.persist(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ObjectData object) {
        entityManager.merge(object);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectData getById(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(ObjectData.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        ObjectData data = getById(id);
        if (data != null)
            entityManager.remove(data);
    }

}
```

And Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ObjectDataService {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectDAO dao;

    public void create(ObjectData data){
        dao.create(data);
    }

    public void update(ObjectData data){
        dao.update(data);
    }

    public ObjectData getById(Long id){
        return dao.getById(id);
    }

    public void delete(Long id){
        dao.delete(id);
    }
}
```

However after I create object I still have to manually call update for it to update, if I have to call update manually after each change what are benefits of using this model? Also both schemas appear, but sub-objects are not being added even after manual update, why is that so?

Comment: Can you explain `but sub-objects are not being added even after manual update` ? What was the update you're talking about ?

Comment: I created new ObjectData, set its name, path, and added 2 UnitData, then called update. units_data table however remained empty, even though my object appeared in object_data.

Comment: Please add it to the question. However, that seems perfectly fine to me. It's the way to do so and your expectations are how the system should behave. I don't see what could have caused that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write so much code if you use CrudRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

Refer example : https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Example 1.1. CrudRepository interface

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
extends Repository<T, ID> {
                                                                                                                   (1)
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
                                                                                                                   (2)
T findOne(ID primaryKey);
                                                                                                                   (3)
Iterable<T> findAll();

Long count();
                                                                                                                   (4)
void delete(T entity);
                                                                                                                   (5)
boolean exists(ID primaryKey);
                                                                                                                   (6)
// … more functionality omitted.
}
```

1
Saves the given entity.
2
Returns the entity identified by the given id.
3
Returns all entities.
4
Returns the number of entities.
5
Deletes the given entity.
6
Indicates whether an entity with the given id exists.
++ Good Query capabilities. for example findByLastNameAndFirstName() search on two fields. This support is provided out of box by spring with JPA.

Refer CRUD operation out of box at https://github.com/Roshanmutha/rcmutha-springdatarepository/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rcmutha/springjpa/Application.java

Refer Query Capabilities at https://github.com/Roshanmutha/rcmutha-springdatarepository/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rcmutha/springjpa/service/CustomerRepository.java

Also @Transactional provide transaction support with JPA which revert complete transaction if something fails.

Comment: That works great so far. Thank you. I used @Transactional because I have Many to One relation in my database, and I want to revert transaction if any of subobjects fails to update. Is that not a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

The objects your data layer is returning are instantaneous copies of your database entities.

You still have to call `update` (on your service) to commit changes to your database.

And you should be aware that every object you're using in a thread at any time might be (and it's better to always consider it **IS**) different from what is stored in database.